# QuickCheck: How to use exhaustiveness checker to prevent forgotten constructors of a sum type

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I have a Haskell data type like

```
data Mytype
  = C1
  | C2 Char
  | C3 Int String
```

If I `case` on a `Mytype` and forget to handle one of the cases, GHC gives me a warning (*exhaustiveness check*).

I now want to write a QuickCheck `Arbitrary` instance to generate `MyTypes` like:

```
instance Arbitrary Mytype where
  arbitrary = do
    n <- choose (1, 3 :: Int)
    case n of
      1 -> C1
      2 -> C2 <$> arbitrary
      3 -> C3 <$> arbitrary <*> someCustomGen
```

The problem with this is that I can add a new alternative to `Mytype` and forget to update the Arbitrary instance, thus having my tests not test that alternative.

I would like to find a way of using GHC's exhaustiveness checker to remind me of forgotten cases in my Arbitrary instance.

The best I've come up with is

```
arbitrary = do
  x <- elements [C1, C2 undefined, C3 undefined undefined]
  case x of
    C1     -> C1
    C2 _   -> C2 <$> arbitrary
    C3 _ _ -> C3 <$> arbitrary <*> someCustomGen
```

But it doesn't really feel elegant.

I intuitively feel that there's no 100% clean solution to this, but would appreciate anything that reduces the chance of forgetting such cases - especially in a big project where code and tests are separated.

Comment: Just a note: One can write `C2{}` instead of `C2 _` and so on which at least makes the syntax a bit nicer.

Comment: Note that the `undefined` thing will fail if the constructor is strict.

Comment: Is there some reason you don't want to just derive the Arbitrary instance automatically with TH?

Comment: @DanBurton Yes, I wanted to hint at that with my use of `someCustomGen`. If I have some invariant not captured by the type system, or otherwise want to influence with what probability alternatives are generated (to make it more likely to generate non-trivial cases), I have to customise parts of the Arbitrary instance (e.g. with QuickCheck's `frequency` function).

Comment: Great question! I have opened https://github.com/nick8325/quickcheck/issues/267 to ask what the recommended solution is today.

Answer (score 2):

I implemented a solution with TemplateHaskell, you can find a prototype at https://gist.github.com/nh2/d982e2ca4280a03364a8. With this you can write:

```
instance Arbitrary Mytype where
  arbitrary = oneof $(exhaustivenessCheck ''Mytype [|
      [ pure C1
      , C2 <$> arbitrary
      , C3 <$> arbitrary <*> arbitrary
      ]
    |])
```

It works like this: You give it a type name (like `''Mytype`) and an expression (in my case a list of `arbitrary` style `Gen`s). It gets the list of all constructors for that type name and checks whether the expression contains all of these constructors at least once. If you just added a constructor but forgot to add it to the Arbitrary instance, this function will warn you at compile time.

This is how it's implemented with TH:

```
exhaustivenessCheck :: Name -> Q Exp -> Q Exp
exhaustivenessCheck tyName qList = do
  tyInfo <- reify tyName
  let conNames = case tyInfo of
        TyConI (DataD _cxt _name _tyVarBndrs cons _derives) -> map conNameOf cons
        _ -> fail "exhaustivenessCheck: Can only handle simple data declarations"

  list <- qList
  case list of
    input@(ListE l) -> do
      -- We could be more specific by searching for `ConE`s in `l`
      let cons = toListOf tinplate l :: [Name]
      case filter (`notElem` cons) conNames of
        [] -> return input
        missings -> fail $ "exhaustivenessCheck: missing case: " ++ show missings
    _ -> fail "exhaustivenessCheck: argument must be a list"
```

I'm using `GHC.Generics` to easily traverse the syntax tree of the `Exp`: With `toListOf tinplate exp :: [Name]` (from `lens`) I can easily find all `Name`s in the whole `exp`.

I was surprised that the types from `Language.Haskell.TH` do not have `Generic` instances, and neither (with current GHC 7.8) do `Integer` or `Word8` - `Generic` instances for these are required because they appear in `Exp`. So I added them as orphan instances (for most things, `StandaloneDeriving` does it but for primitive types like `Integer` I had to copy-paste instances as `Int` has them).

The solution is not perfect because it doesn't use the exhaustiveness checker like `case` does, but as we agree, that's not possible while staying DRY, and this TH solution is DRY.

One possible improvement/alternative would be to write a TH function that does this check for all Arbitrary instances in a whole module at once instead of calling `exhaustivenessCheck` inside each Arbitrary instance.

Answer (score 2):

You want to ensure that your code behaves in a particular way; the simplest way to check the behaviour of code is to test it.

In this case, the desired behaviour is that each constructor gets reasonable coverage in tests. We can check that with a simple test:

```
allCons xs = length xs > 100 ==> length constructors == 3
             where constructors = nubBy eqCons xs
                   eqCons  C1       C1      = True
                   eqCons  C1       _       = False
                   eqCons (C2 _)   (C2 _)   = True
                   eqCons (C2 _)    _       = False
                   eqCons (C3 _ _) (C3 _ _) = True
                   eqCons (C3 _ _)  _       = False
```

This is pretty naive, but it's a good first shot. Its advantages:

- `eqCons` will trigger an exhaustiveness warning if new constructors are added, which is what you want
- It checks that your instance is handling all constructors, which is what you want
- It *also* checks that all constructors are *actually generated* with some useful probability (in this case at least 1%)
- It *also* checks that your instance is usable, eg. doesn't hang

Its disadvantages:

- Requires a large amount of test data, in order to filter out those with length > 100
- `eqCons` is quite verbose, since a catch-all `eqCons _ _ = False` would bypass the exhaustiveness check
- Uses magic numbers 100 and 3
- Not very generic

There are ways to improve this, eg. we can compute the constructors using the Data.Data module:

```
allCons xs = sufficient ==> length constructors == consCount
             where sufficient   = length xs > 100 * consCount
                   constructors = length . nub . map toConstr $ xs
                   consCount    = dataTypeConstrs (head xs)
```

This loses the compile-time exhaustiveness check, but it's redundant as long as we test regularly and our code has become more generic.

If we really want the exhaustiveness check, there are a few places where we could shoe-horn it back in:

```
allCons xs = sufficient ==> length constructors == consCount
             where sufficient   = length xs > 100 * consCount
                   constructors = length . nub . map toConstr $ xs
                   consCount    = length . dataTypeConstrs $ case head xs of
                                                                  x@(C1)     -> x
                                                                  x@(C2 _)   -> x
                                                                  x@(C3 _ _) -> x
```

Notice that we use consCount to eliminate the magic `3` completely. The magic `100` (which determined the minimum required frequency of a constructor) now scales with consCount, but that just requires even more test data!

We can solve that quite easily using a newtype:

```
consCount = length (dataTypeConstrs C1)

newtype MyTypeList = MTL [MyType] deriving (Eq,Show)

instance Arbitrary MyTypeList where
  arbitrary = MTL <$> vectorOf (100 * consCount) arbitrary
  shrink (MTL xs) = MTL (shrink <$> xs)

allCons (MTL xs) = length constructors == consCount
                   where constructors = length . nub . map toConstr $ xs
```

We can put a simple exhaustiveness check in there somewhere if we like, eg.

```
instance Arbitrary MyTypeList where
  arbitrary = do x <- arbitrary
                 MTL <$> vectorOf (100 * consCount) getT
              where getT = do x <- arbitrary
                              return $ case x of
                                            C1     -> x
                                            C2 _   -> x
                                            C3 _ _ -> x
  shrink (MTL xs) = MTL (shrink <$> xs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I exploit an unused variable `_x`. This is not really more elegant than your solution, though.

```
instance Arbitrary Mytype where
  arbitrary = do
    let _x = case _x of C1 -> _x ; C2 _ -> _x ; C3 _ _ -> _x
    n <- choose (1, 3 :: Int)
    case n of
      1 -> C1
      2 -> C2 <$> arbitrary
      3 -> C3 <$> arbitrary <*> someCustomGen
```

Of course, one has to keep the last `case` coherent with the dummy definition of `_x`, so it is not completely DRY.

Alternatively, one might exploit Template Haskell to build a compile-time assert checking that the constructors in `Data.Data.dataTypeOf` are the expected ones. This assert has to be kept coherent with the `Arbitrary` instance, so this is not completely DRY either.

If you do not need custom generators, I believe `Data.Data` can be exploited to generate `Arbitrary` instances via Template Haskell (I think I saw some code doing exactly that, but I can't remember where). In this way, there's no chance the instance can miss a constructor.

Comment: Another possibility is to use `GHC.Generics` to derive the arbitrary instance. `GHC.Generics` is very well suited in cases where you can say what to do for Sums (Constructors of a data type) and Products (Fields of a data constructor), which this one should be an instance of.

Comment: @bennofs Unfortunately `GHC.Generics` only help if you want to use the default `arbitrary` in all fields. In that case, yes, they are great for this purpose, but in my case it is important that I can customise the instance (I tried hinting at that by including `someCustomGen`).

Comment: The self-recursive way you propose is certainly nicer than my `undefined`s.

Comment: If I add a `C4` constructor how is the above code going to catch the missing case?

Comment: @DanielVelkov It will emit a warning "Non exhaustive patterns", like the code posted by nh2 in his question.

Comment: @chi and what if I update the `case _x` part but not the second part of the function which generates the random values?

Comment: @DanielVelkov This is indeed a shortcoming. That's what I meant when I wrote that the case must be kept coherent with _x, so this is not completely DRY, nor much more elegant than the original nh2's code. It does not force the instance to be correct, but it helps the programmer in remembering to fix the code for new constructors.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the [`generic-random`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-random) library:

```
{-# language DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# language TypeOperators #-}

import Generic.Random
import GHC.Generics
import Test.QuickCheck

data Mytype
  = C1
  | C2 Char
  | C3 Int String
  deriving Generic

instance Arbitrary Mytype where
  arbitrary = genericArbitraryG customGens uniform
    where
      customGens :: Gen String :+ ()
      customGens = someCustomGen :+ ()

someCustomGen :: Gen String
someCustomGen = undefined
```

`genericArbitraryG` takes care of generating each constructor of `MyType`. In this case we use `uniform` to get a uniform distribution of constructors. With `customGens` we define that each `String` field in `Mytype` is generated with `someCustomGen`.

See [`Generic.Random.Tutorial`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-random-1.3.0.0/docs/Generic-Random-Tutorial.html) for more examples.